# Support for Angular 2 in Breeze

Tags: angularjs, breeze, hottowel

I have a project developed until 6 months ago, an ASP.NET 4.5 C# web site that uses the HotTowel.Angular template of John Papa (the project was started in Visual Studio 2013, now is updated to Visual Studio 2015).

The project uses Angular 1.5.7.

In the Breeze site i'm not finding infos about Angular 2, and HotTowel seems outdated (i'm not seeing updates after 2013).

What should i do? rewrite from scratch the javascript part?

Comment: Breeze works about the same in Angular 1 & 2.  But you are right, some documentation is needed explaining that.  In the meantime, take a look at the [TempHire Angular2 Sample](https://github.com/Breeze/temphire.angular2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stay with angular 1.* as long as you want and migrate parts of your app step by step. At the moment there is no need to rewrite the whole app to Angular 2. 
Also you can look at https://github.com/ngParty/ng-metadata for a future upgrade path.

Breeze actively develops a new bridge for Angular 2 at https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.bridge.angular2

Answer (score 0):

If you do move to Angular 2 (or at least typescript) make sure you check out the fantastic [breeze tooling](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.tooling) that the Breeze team created.

I stumbled across it by mistake when trying to get breeze going in Angular 2.
The breeze tooling will generate all your typescript types for all of your domain entities with a single command. It even will wire up all your entity constructors, etc to the breeze metadataStore for you.

To me it's worth the investment to convert code to typescript to get the intellisense and type checking for free on all my entities.